# How to set top space constraint for specific device in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am using `Xcode7.3.1`. I have setup `Autolayout` on my screen.It's working perfectly in on iphone5,6,etc.But in `iphone4s` can not see the screen properly.
This screen i added top space to 150. But bottom part can’t be visible when I run the app in `iphone4s`.Here i attach the screen look like in iphone4S.  How to fix this issue?

[image]

Top Space look like in xib

[image]

Comment: can you please post the snap of constraints hierarchy?

Comment: Add your proper requirement(like you want your view in middle or you want it with some static space) and current constraint in question to get proper solution!!

Answer (score 6):

As a quick option you can setup an invisible spacer view which height is relative to a screen height: add "Equal height" constraint to a main view and set multiplier to, say, 0.1. Thus your spacer will take 10% of the screen.
Then you can use this view as a top constraint.

Here is an example in Interface Builder. I colored the spacer just to show it here, so don't forget to set its background color to "Clear color".
[image]

Comment: Simplistic solutions are mostly, if not always, the best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an outlet for top constraint and through code you need to set this top constraint value as given below :

```
@IBOutlet weak var topConstForSubView: NSLayoutConstraint!

if  iPHONE4 {
    self.topConstForSubView.constant = 60
}
```

Comment: You can similarly set up an NSLayoutConstraint subclass to conveniently set a special constant for iPhone 4 using an IBInspectable property.

Answer (score 0):

as a variant of @Sarabjit Singh's answer:
May be a better/different solution is take a **scale** for constant correction:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *YConstraint;

...

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    if (scale == 2) {
        self.YConstraint.constant = 75; // for example
    } else if (scale == 3) {
        self.YConstraint.constant = 105; // for example
    }
}
```